# C# MySQL Query is not working

Tags: c#, mysql

Error message is,

> Connection must be valid and open.

Is this code wrong? How can i solve the problem?

```
string strConn = "server = localhost; user = root; database = ****; port = 3306; password = ****; Charset = utf8";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(strConn))
{
    MySqlCommand insertCommand = new MySqlCommand();

    conn.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO master (col_name, col_code)" +
        " SELECT * from (select '" + _name[i] + "', '" + _code[i] + "') as tmp" +
        " WHERE NOT EXISTS (" +
        " SELECT col_code FROM master WHERE col_code = '" + _name[i] + "') limit 1;";

        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Where's code you pointing to?

Comment: Could you insert your code here?

Comment: I added image, but cant load.

Comment: What do you mean by "cant load" ?

Comment: Don't post an image, post your code instead.

Answer (score 2):

Before your `for loop` need to set connection for your CommandObject like:

```
InsertCommand.Connection = conn;
```

Comment: using (MySqlconnection conn = new MysqlConnection(strconn))

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the connection to your command by using the connection object you created `conn`.

```
MySqlCommand insertCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
```

So, your code goes like this:

```
string strConn = "server = localhost; user = root; database = ****; port = 3306; password = ****; Charset = utf8";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(strConn))
{
    MySqlCommand insertCommand = conn.CreateCommand();

    conn.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO master (col_name, col_code)" +
        " SELECT * from (select '" + _name[i] + "', '" + _code[i] + "') as tmp" +
        " WHERE NOT EXISTS (" +
        " SELECT col_code FROM master WHERE col_code = '" + _name[i] + "') limit 1;";

        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    conn.Close();  //you don't need this.
}
```

No need to close the connection by `conn.Close();` because the connection gets automatically closed when the `using` block is exited.

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(strConn))
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: It wors!
Thank you :)

Comment: @lovendon if it works then the appropriate response will be to vote up and mark it as answered :)